# SQL: select different columns to be returned from a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic-columns

Let's say I have a table `mytable` with several columns (this is not entirely true, see Edit):

```
mytable
id    data        description          created_at      viewed_times
1      10        'help wanted'      '20180101 04:23'       45
2      20    'customer registered'  '20180504 03:12'        1
...
```

I created a stored procedure that returns data from this table. The problem is that sometimes I need it to return only `id` and `data` columns, and sometimes I need additional information, like `description`, `created_at` etc.

My idea is to create three dummy variables `@display_description`, `@display_created_date`, `@display_viewed_times`. When a dummy variable equals 1, I display corresponding column. For example, for command

```
exec my_procedure @display_description = 1
```

I expect output

```
id    data        description        
1      10        'help wanted'      
2      20    'customer registered'  
...
```

How I implement it in the procedure is:

```
if @display_description = 1
    select id, data, description from mytable
else 
    select id, data from mytable
```

The problem is, if I want to have 3 switches (one for each column), I have to write 8 conditions in my `if` statement. (My `select` statement is a complex one. In addition, some of the columns like `viewed_times` have to be calculated, if I want them displayed. Therefore, writing many `if` statements makes the query very clumsy, and I want to avoid that)

Is there an easy way to select columns based on the switches? And if no, what approach would you recommend to return different number of columns from a stored procedure?

Edit: Sorry, I sad that the table `mytable` already exists with all columns. That is not true, some of the columns have to be calculated before displayed. For example, column `viewed_times` doesn't exist. To display it, I'll need to do the following:

```
if @display_description = 1
    ~ several selects to calculate the column viewed_times ~
    select id, data, description from mytable join table in which I just calculated the viewed_times column
else 
    select id, data from mytable
```

Calculating these columns is time consuming, and I would like to do that only if I need those columns displayed.

That's why dynamic SQL will probably not work

Update: I accepted the answer with Dynamic SQL, but what I did is the following:

```
if @display_viewed_times = 1
begin   
    ~ calculate column viewed_times ~
    update my_table 
    ~ add column viewed_times to the table my_table ~
end
```

for each of the optional columns. Then I return the table using

```
select * from my_table
```

which gives me different number of columns depending on the swithces

Comment: You can use dynamic query. Also google for Kitchen SInk

Comment: Why not just use `select . . . from`?  What value is a stored procedure giving you?

Comment: A stored procedure that returns different result set shapes depending on the parameters passed is a flawed interface design, IMHO.

Comment: I have to agree with @DanGuzman. Write each permutation as a separate procedure, then let the calling application decide which one to call.

Comment: @EricBrandt in this case, I'll have to write 8 different procedures (including and excluding each column) with basically the same code. Or did I get you wrong?

Comment: @DanGuzman then what design would you recommend? My stored procedure returns several tables. In one of the tables, I need sometimes to calculate some additional information, which may be one of the three columns. Sometimes I need just one column, sometimes all of them etc. Calculating each column takes time, so I want to calculate it only if I want to display it.

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk, that's my first impression, yes. Typically, you want a stored procedure to have an output with a predictable shape so the calling application knows what to expect. There are exceptions, of course, so do as you will.

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk, I suggest different stored procedures. Yes, that's more code but much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be the use Dynamic SQL. This is pseudo-SQL, as there an absence of information here to achieve a full answer. It's also untested, as i don't have much/any data to really run this against.

```
--Your input parameters
DECLARE @description bit, @createdate bit, @viewedtimes bit /*...etc...*/;

--Now the SP
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT ' +
           STUFF(CONCAT(N','+ NCHAR(10) + N'       ' + CASE WHEN @description = 1 THEN QUOTENAME(N'description') END,
                        N','+ NCHAR(10) + N'       ' + CASE WHEN @createdate = 1 THEN QUOTENAME(N'created_at') END,
                        N','+ NCHAR(10) + N'       ' + CASE WHEN @viewedtimes = 1 THEN QUOTENAME(N'viewed_times') END),1,9,N'') + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM YourTable' + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'WHERE...;';
PRINT @SQL; --your best debugging friend.
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL /*N'@someParam int', @someParam = @inParam*/;
```

Ensure that you properly parametrise your query when you use Dyanmic SQL. **Don't** concatenate your string!!!

For example, the correct format would be `N'WHERE yourColumn = @yourParam AND OtherColumn = @otherParam'` and then provide the values of `@yourParam` and `@otherParam` in `sp_executesql` (as I have demonstrated within the comment).

**Don't, however, do something like:** `N'WHERE yourColumn = ''' + @myParam + N''' AND otherColumn = ' + CONVERT(varchar(5),@secondParam)`. This would be open to SQL injection (which is not your friend).

Comment: Your answer definitely works in the setting that I described, and I'm sure it'll help to someone having the same problem. I forgot to mention, that some of the columns of the table `mytable` have to be calculated (think of `mytable` as a result of the procedure), and the calculations may be heavy, so I want it calculated only if I will display it. Thus, the code in @SQL will have several `SELECT ` statements, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk then instead of simply having `QUOTENAME(N'description')` include your expression. For example `CASE WHEN @description = 1 THEN N'SUM(CASE [description] WHEN ''Cheese'' THEN [Price] END) AS [description]' END`. You can still include expressions in dynamic SQL.

Comment: I'll probably do that if I don't find another solution. The reason i want to avoid that is because the code becomes unreadable when converted to string. A special thanks for the tip about injection! I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @AlexandrKapshuk that's what your best friend is for.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the stored procedure to a table valued function and modify the outer "select from".

So for example:

```
if($value1 === 1)
  $sql = "SELECT c1, c2 FROM dbo.my_udf";
elseif($value1 ===2)
  $sql = "SELECT c1, c3, c4 FROM dbo.my_udf";
```

Comment: That's not T-SQL. It appears you've assumed the application language the OP is using (is that PHP?), however, they make no mention of that. At best, this is a very wild guess. Having multiple functions, for the same thing, doesn't make a very good scalable solution either. Should the query need to change, you have 11 functions to change, not 1.

Comment: Of course this is not T-SQL. My suggestion is to modify the SP to a function.

The code just shows how to select different columns from a function.
I can't post the code of the required function as there is no code of the SP.